# What does the -ada ending mean?

Tags: gramática

I am studying Spanish with the Michel Thomas Method.

It has the following example:

> la cena está preparada
>
> dinner is prepared

What does the `ada` ending in `preparada` mean?
`Preparada` comes from `preparar` but I'm not sure why they have used `ada`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*preparar* has the past participle *preparado(a)*. The choice of *-ada* or *-ado* will depend on what the noun is.

> La cena está prepar**ada** → *cena* is feminine, so it must agree with the ending *-ada*.
>   El cerdo está prepar**ado** → *cerdo* is masculine, so it must agree with the ending *-ado*.